# How to connect to an EC2 cassandra instance in ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, cassandra

I am new to cassandra so I followed [this guide](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/install/install_ami) on how to get Cassandra set up on an EC2 instance.  I have gotten it all set up and ready to go but for some reason I'm not able to connect from ruby. Here is what I have been trying:

```
 require 'cassandra'
 client = Cassandra.new('PERSON', 'ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9160')
   # =>
   #  <Cassandra:0x100cda3b0
   #    @auto_discover_nodes = true,
   #    @column_name_class = {},
   #    @column_name_maker = {},
   #    @is_super = {},
   #    @sub_column_name_class = {},
   #    @sub_column_name_maker = {},
   #    attr_accessor :keyspace = "PERSON",
   #    attr_reader :servers = [
   #      [0] "ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9160"
   #    ],
   #    attr_reader :thrift_client_class = ThriftClient < AbstractThriftClient,
   #    attr_reader :thrift_client_options = {
   #      :transport_wrapper => Thrift::FramedTransport < Thrift::BaseTransport,
   #      :thrift_client_class => ThriftClient < AbstractThriftClient,
   #      :protocol => Thrift::BinaryProtocolAccelerated < Thrift::BinaryProtocol
   #    }
   #  >
```

Then when I tried to use the client, I get this error:

```
client.keyspaces
  #=> ThriftClient::NoServersAvailable: No live servers in [ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9160].
```

I am able to connect via SSH so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Update:

My security group includes:

port: **9160**

protocol: **tcp**

source: **sg-xxxxxxxx**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the "source" of the connection into the Cassandra server?

The security group you are using only opens up port 9160 to instances in the group **sg-xxxxxxxx**.  If you are trying to connect from anywhere else (like the outside world) you will not be successful.

Comment: what would I change this to so that I could connect?

Comment: @Josh That's why I am asking for the "source".  For example, if you wanted to open it to the whole wide world you would change the source to: 0.0.0.0/0.

Comment: @Josh That's great. However, I recommend reading the docs on AWS security groups and working towards something a bit more restrictive.  The way it is now, everybody on the planet can access this server just as well as you can.  http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#concepts-security

Comment: I will go back in when I am ready to put any real data in there, for now, I am just playing around with it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to check:

- do you have a firewall running on the client and/or the server?
- do you allow access in your EC2 security group from your client to your server?